# How to show one random post from a specific post type for 24 hours then refresh

Tags: wordpress

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but I was wondering if there is anyway to create a Wordpress query that will select a post at 00:00 in the morning and show that post for 24 hours. When it hits 00:00 the following morning it should refresh and show anther random post for another 24 hours. Is this possible, if so how?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [WordPress Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) and the [WP_Query class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

```
$random_id = '';
if ( false === ( $random_id = get_transient( 'some_random_post_id' ) ) ) {
     // The transient expired, so create another
     $args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => 1, #return one value
      'orderby'        => 'rand',
      'post_type'      => 'yourposttype'
        );
     $single_post_query = new WP_Query( $args );
     while( $single_post_query->have_posts() ){
         $single_post_query->the_post();
         $random_id = get_the_ID(); 
         set_transient('some_random_post_id', $random_id, 60*60*24); # save the ID returned
     }

}
//do your stuff with $random_id as the post id.
```

Note that it may not be exactly 24 hours since WordPress will update its transient when someone visits your website. Also, if you are using WordPress 3.5 or above you may use the constant `DAY_IN_SECONDS` instead of `60*60*24`.

Comment: Hi RRikesh, thanks for your answer, how would I do this with a custom post type? Also do I need to replace some_random_post_id ? Or leave as is? Thanks

Comment: You can change it to something you'll remember. For the custom post type, you need to pass the `post_type` parameter in the `$args`. I'm updating my answer for that.